# Power BI - search and include and exclude certain strings

Tags: powerbi

I have simple table:

```
Column            Desired result
Messi Ronaldo     0
Ronaldo           0
Messi Pogba       0
Messi alala       1
```

And I try to count how many times Messi is in the string and Ronaldo and Pogba are not present.

The code I have got is:

```
Desired result = 
IF (ISBLANK ( SEARCH ( "Messi", 'Table'[Column], 1, BLANK () ) )
&&
(
ISBLANK ( SEARCH ( "Ronaldo", 'Table'[Column], 1, BLANK () ) )
||ISBLANK ( SEARCH ( "Pogba", 'Table'[Column], 1, BLANK () ) )
)
,
0,
1)
```

But it does not exclude Ronaldo or Pogba?

Current(wrong) results

```
Column           Current results
Messi Ronaldo    1
Ronaldo          0
Messi Pogba      1
Messi alala      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Desired result = 
    IF (NOT(ISBLANK ( SEARCH ( "Messi",   'Table'[Column], 1, BLANK () ) ))
        &&  ISBLANK ( SEARCH ( "Ronaldo", 'Table'[Column], 1, BLANK () ) )
        &&  ISBLANK ( SEARCH ( "Pogba",   'Table'[Column], 1, BLANK () ) ),
        1,
        0)
```

This returns `1` if searching for "Messi" doesn't return a blank but the search for "Ronaldo" and "Pogba" do return a blank.